# Username available in all templates

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid

I'm trying to make the currently logged in username available in all templates. I can receive it from `pyramid.security.authenticated_userid`, but to do that I need the request object. I tried to go via the `BeforeRender` subscription, but as far as I can tell, the request in not passed to that callback.

How else can I make the username available everywhere (or in the base template really)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common method is to attach the user object to the request via this [cookbook recipe](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/dev/authentication.html).

Another possibility is to attach it as you suggested using a `BeforeRender` subscriber. The `request` is available from the `event`:

```py
def add_renderer_globals(event):
    request, context = event['request'], event['context']
    event['user'] = authenticated_userid(request)
```